# When I use "limit" in "strategy.entry" for safe orders in pyramiding, it gives orders at wrong times

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to run DCA strategy with pyramiding orders, but when I use limit in "strategy.entry" for safe orders, it gives orders at wrong times.
The condition "strategy.opentrades == 0 or strategy.position_size == 0" should not create a safeorder, but the strategy ignores this condition and makes purchases.

In other words, although the Base order is closed in the Strategy (although strategy.opentrades == 0), it repeatedly executes 2nd orders as if there is an open position.

I tried many things but couldn't figure it out.

The relevant part of the codes is below

Please help me solve this problem.

```
if (allow_longs==true) and (strategy.position_size == 0 or (strategy.position_size < 0 and short_start_breakeven == 1 )) and window and source_function(source_type) > 0  and (yukari_kirilim and (bull1 == 1)) 
    strategy.entry('Long @', strategy.long, comment = BUY, alert_message = BUY )
    previous_high_value := 0.0      
    original_ttp_value := 0
    original_ttp_value
    short_start_breakeven := 0
    long_start_breakeven := 0



if strategy.opentrades == 1 and maxOrders >= 2
    strategy.entry('Bull #1', strategy.long, qty=quantMultiplied1, limit=strategy.opentrades.entry_price(0) * (1 - avgDown),
     comment="Buy #2 " + str.tostring(avgDown * 100, format.percent))

if (strategy.opentrades == 2 and maxOrders >= 3 and strategy.position_size > 0)
    strategy.entry("Long @", strategy.long, qty=quantMultiplied2, limit=(strategy.opentrades == 2 and maxOrders >= 3 and strategy.position_size > 0) ? strategy.opentrades.entry_price(0) * (1 - avgDown1) : 0,
     comment="Buy #3 " + str.tostring(avgDown1 * 100, format.percent))

// Take Profit!
if take_profit_level <= source_function(source_type) and strategy.position_size > 0 or previous_high_value > 0.0
    if trailing > 0.0
        if previous_high_value > 0.0
            if source_function(source_type) >= previous_high_value
                previous_high_value := source_function(source_type)
                previous_high_value
            else
                previous_high_percent = (previous_high_value - original_ttp_value) * 1.0 / original_ttp_value
                current_high_percent = (source_function(source_type) - original_ttp_value) * 1.0 / original_ttp_value
                if (previous_high_percent - current_high_percent >= trailing) 
                    strategy.close_all(comment= SELL )
                    previous_high_value := 0
                    original_ttp_value := 0
                    original_ttp_value
                    take_profit_level_on := 0
        else
            previous_high_value := source_function(source_type)
            original_ttp_value := source_function(source_type)
            original_ttp_value
 
if  (ll or asagi_kirilim1) and (strategy.position_size > 0) and (close >= (strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + long_breakeven_target)))
    strategy.close_all(comment= SELL)
    previous_high_value := 0
    original_ttp_value := 0
    original_ttp_value
    take_profit_level_on := 0
// Stop loss
if  (strategy.position_size > 0) and (low < long_beakeven) 
    strategy.exit("L Stop",  from_entry = 'Long @', stop = (long_start_breakeven == 1) ? long_beakeven : stop_loss_level, comment= SELL )
    previous_high_value := 0
    original_ttp_value := 0
    original_ttp_value
    take_profit_level_on := 0
```